# Laravel 5.3 cannot access PrimeryKey object

Tags: laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3. I get a wrong value for primaryKey of a table (users table) although i get it properly. It is very strange. Here is my code

```
 protected $table = 'users_tbl';
 protected $primaryKey = "email";
```

The Controller:

```
$user = User::find('alaile@hotmail.com');
dd($user);


#table: "users_tbl"
#primaryKey: "email"
#fillable: array:8 [▶]
#hidden: array:2 [▶]
#connection: null
#keyType: "int"
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
 #attributes: array:15 [▼
  "email" => "alaile@hotmail.com"
  "register" => "1892"
   "section" => "GO"
   "turn" => 92
   ...
```

output the email properly but when I access through the object get 0. However the rest of attributes are ok:

```
 echo $user->email;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $user->register;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $user->section;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $user->turn;
 echo "<br>";
 exit;
```

output

```
 0
 1892
 GO
 92
```

Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot to set the increments to false for laravel to not look for an auto incremented id.

This is something that happen to me before and drove me crazy!!

On your User.php model add this line:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Thanks man i was becoming crazy. It is very clear in laravel documentation. but i dont have this set in other laravel's project and they works ok. Always version 5.2 or less.